# How to get SQLite working in my Flask application?

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, virtualenv

I'm building a web app in Flask. I'm a noob. This is my first app.

I have followed installation instructions for SQLite, and now I have SQLite on my machine.

How do I include SQLite in my app? I need to be able to use SQLite in my app.py

Do I need to include SQLite in the virtual environment? How do I do that?

[Here is the directory I'm working in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcMkG.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in first you should import SQLlite like

```
import sqlite3 # this library is have from first time in your python so no need to download
```

after should create data base like :

```
con = sqlite3.connect('mydatabase.db') # create data base and give name like mydatabase
# but should in last have .db

cur = con.cursor() # for send parameter always you need this
```

after you can create table for your database to store you items like:

```
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS session_id (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,what yo want MESSAGE_TEXT ,pass_word FLOAT )") 

# with cur.execute first can i created id in my table like every project its good 
# its good to create this for store your items in your database and you create..
# any you want like what you want for ex. create name should MESSAGE_TEXT, and..
# password like INTEGER OR FLOAT OR DOUBLE what you want

con.commit()
```

and you can send parameter like this to your table:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO my_table VALUES name,password))

# in here i just send to parameter because we just create to item in our database
# you can create more, like name, password, session or what you want

con.commit() # and again this because should always have
```

If I want to talk about it at all, it will be too much, That's why I shared the link of an article for you here so that you can learn much better and deeper

Link for more here »» [Link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_python.htm)

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_python.htm

Comment: Thank you! I am familiar with how to use SQLite, because I did some class projects with it. But the teacher set up the virtual environment so everything was ready for me. I didn't realise flask is included in python!

Comment: So great bro @JDS, I'm so glad you managed to use it, just tick it if you think the answer is correct, Some people may be confused in the future..